# Ant - Pathelement with wildcard only works in Javac forked mode

Tags: java, ant

I encountered below issue when using Ant.

My ANT script snippets:

```
<path id="id.compile.classpath">
  <pathelement location="src/compile_lib1/*" />
  <pathelement location="src/compile_lib2/*" />
</path>

<javac srcdir="${module.root}/${src.root}" destdir="${swap.target.classes}"
  nowarn="${javac.nowarn}" debug="${javac.debug}" fork="${javac.fork}"
  classpathref="id.compile.classpath" includeAntRuntime="${javac.includeAntRuntime}">
  <include name="**/*.java"/>
</javac>
```

When set fork=”true” in javac task, the wildcard pathelement works fine, but when forked is set to false, Ant seems failed to interpret wildcard correctly. (compilation failed,  due to classpath error).

Any suggestions
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using a wildcard `pathelement`, use a `fileset` and let Ant expand out the wildcard for you.

```
<path id="id.compile.classpath">
  <fileset dir="src/compile_lib1" includes="*.jar" />
  <fileset dir="src/compile_lib2" includes="*.jar" />
</path>
```

Comment: understand, just want to know why that doesn't work in my case

Comment: @foolhunger Java doesn't support wildcards in the classpath, neither does ANT. See: http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path

Comment: @foolhunger The section on wildcards in the [Oracle documentation about classpaths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html) says that "Expansion of wildcards is done early, prior to the invocation of a program's main method, rather than late, during the class-loading process itself" - which suggests that in forked mode the JVM launcher will expand out the wildcard and pass the expanded version of the path to the compiler class.  In non-forked mode this won't happen, and the compiler would see the literal `*` which it doesn't know how to deal with.